# How to update a value in the bank, subtracting or adding the old amount

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm developing an API for a warehouse system, and in the update method I need to update the amount of my stock/inventory (example, the entrance has 4 meters of wood, in the edit I changed it to 3 meters, so I remove 4 meters from the inventory which would be the previous value, and then I add the 3 meters of the edit), I'm having trouble on how to get this data that was inserted when my entry in the inventory was created, a part of my code:

```
public function update(EntradaUpdateFormRequest $request, $id)
{
    $entrada = Entrada::findOrFail($id);
    //there's a lot of code in this part...
    //and below is the logic of moving the inventory table...
    // logic to update or add quantity of items in inventory
                $inventario = Inventario::where('departamento_id','=',$entrada->departamento_id)
                                        ->where('local_id','=',$entrada->local_id)
                                        ->where('item_id','=',$entrada_items["item_id"])
                                        ->first();

                if ($inventario) {
                    $inventario->quantidade - //this is the biggest obstacle, I think the scheme would be to subtract the previous total, and then add the new total, but as
                    //do to change the value that was added when this record was created in the store method.
                    $inventario->quantidade += $entrada_items["quantidade"];
                    $inventario->save();
                } else {
                    $inventario = new Inventario();
                    $inventario->departamento_id = $entrada->departamento_id;
                    $inventario->item_id = $entrada_items["item_id"];
                    $inventario->local_id = $entrada->local_id;
                    $inventario->quantidade = $entrada_items["quantidade"];
                    $inventario->qtd_alerta = 0;
                    $inventario->save();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just affect the quantity directly

```
if ($inventario) {
    $inventario->quantidade = $entrada_items["quantidade"];
    $inventario->save();
} else {
```

Comment: Because in my inventory->quantity there will be invoice records, every time there is an invoice entry, there may be the same items and a quantity is added... and the logic I'm implementing now is to update any record that I have to others some invoice, eg. I entered a note and put the item id=1 with 4 units, but I entered it wrong, I have to enter the system and update, let's go, I'm going to enter 3, I can't enter the 3 directly in the inventory, which subtracts the 4 from the previous entry and add the 3, to update the total in the inventory, did you understand?

Comment: @Meliodas so the solution you are looking for is related more to your business rules and your structural logic than to brute programming logic. In that case, no one can help you on stack overflow and your question is probably off topic.

Comment: OK, thank you friend. i did it once in my code and my code managed to solve this problem but it got too verbose. I'm going to ask my supervisor for instructions, to check if my logic and code are correct and if there's a way to improve, because I'm finding it very polluted.